# Override function parameters - typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following **config.tsx** file-

```
const AuthConfig = {
    base_uri: 'https://google.com',
    info: {
        country: 'Norway',
        continent: 'Europe',
    }
};
export default AuthConfig;
```

I am passing the content of this config file as a parameter in some other function call **outside the config.tsx** file.

`import config from './config'`

`myFunction(config)`

**Question**- Is it possible to override a value (say "continent") coming from config file at the time of function call?

Comment: You can but that will be muting the original object you can use things like spread or map which gives you a copy to work with.

Comment: This way it wouldn't impact other references with your base object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it with the spread operator or `Object.assign`

```
 myFunction({...config, info: {...config.info, continent: 'America'}})
```

Or

```
myFunction(Object.assign(config, {info: Object.assign(config.info, {continent: 'America'})}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply cast the `config` to `any` type and then you can update the value for `continent` like:

```
import config from './config'

(<any>config).continent = "AnotherOne";

// This is for debugging purpose
console.log( config )

myFunction(config);
```

If we don't cast the `config` to any, we will get an error like:

> Property 'continent' does not exist on type '{ base_uri: string; info: { country: string; continent: string; }; }'.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to change the values, but not the properties. spread the Object

```js
const AuthConfig = {
    base_uri: 'https://google.com',
    info: {
        country: 'Norway',
        continent: 'Europe',
    }
};
export default AuthConfig;

const toSend = {
   ...AuthService,
   info: { ...AuthService.info, continent: "Some Else" }
}

myFunc(toSend);
```

But if instead you want to alter the Object Structure. TypeScript will cry.
So you need to create a `ObjectLiteral` type

```js
export interface ObjectLiteral {
  [x: string]: any;
}
```